# Thingsquare Router-Node

Tags: contiki

I´m newbie with Thingsquare

I'm traying to create a IP64 Gateway with MB851 Board (STM32W108CC microprocessor)

I send and receive data (IPv6 Radio) using 2 MB851 Boards with Thingsquare udp-multicast example.

I modified mist-mb851 platform to include an enc28j60-arch.c file to implement the platform code of SPI functions that are called by the enc28j60 driver
I modified ip64-conf.h to include enc28j60 driver and fallback interface

---

```
include "ip64-eth-interface.h"                                      

include "enc28j60-ip64-driver.h"                                    

define IP64_CONF_UIP_FALLBACK_INTERFACE ip64_eth_interface

define IP64_CONF_INPUT                  ip64_eth_interface_input

define IP64_CONF_DHCP                   1

define IP64_CONF_ETH_DRIVER             enc28j60_ip64_driver
```

---

I modified Contiki/platform/mb851 to include STM32 PeripheralLibs to create the SPI driver

The enj28j60 driver is tested

I compile the Thingsquare Router-Node example but when initialize the DHCP process

```
ip64_init();--->ip64_ipv4_dhcp_init();--->ip64_dhcpc_request();--->handle_dhcp();--->send_discover();
```

Nothing happens

Debugging the code when `tcpip_ipv6_output();` function is call to send the packet the function `ip64_6to4(...);` fails and i don´t know why

Best Regards

Comment: Have you checked that the following lines of code are present in the platform-conf.h? #undef UIP_FALLBACK_INTERFACE #define UIP_FALLBACK_INTERFACE ip64_uip_fallback_interface

Comment: Yes, this lines are presents in my thingsquare\platform\mist-mb851eth\mist-mb851eth-platform-conf.h file Best Regards,